# Apollo Graph QL: parent is not defined

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

So I'm trying to set up my Apollo server and I'm facing this error that says: `ReferenceError: parent is not defined` which I have passed as parameter to the function.

```
import { User, Landing, Category } from './resolvers';

export const resolves = {
  Query: {
    UserDelete: User.UserDelete(parent, args),
    UserAuth: User.UserAuth(parent, args),
    UserView: User.UserView(parent, args),
    UserLandings: User.UserLandings(parent, args),

    CategoriesView: Category.CategoriesView(parent, args),
    CategoryView: Category.CategoryView(parent, args),
    CategoryDelete: Category.CategoryDelete(parent, args),

    LandingDelete: Landing.LandingDelete(parent, args),
    LandingUp: Landing.LandingUp(parent, args),
    LandingDown: Landing.LandingDown(parent, args),
    LandingView: Landing.LandingView(parent, args),
    LandingsView: Landing.LandingsView(parent, args),
  },
  Mutation: {
    UserRegister: User.UserRegister(parent, args),
    UserUpdate: User.UserUpdate(parent, args),
    LandingCreate: Landing.LandingCreate(parent, args),
    LandingUpdate: Landing.LandingUpdate(parent, args),
    CategoryCreate: Category.CategoryCreate(parent, args),
    CategoryUpdate: Category.CategoryUpdate(parent, args),
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the function arguments properly. Try:

```
import { User, Landing, Category } from './resolvers';

export const resolves = {
  Query: {
    UserDelete: (parent,args) => User.UserDelete(parent, args),
    UserAuth: (parent,args) => User.UserAuth(parent, args),
    etc…
```